# Create EAR with Maven and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ear, maven-ear-plugin

I have a web-application(TestWeb) and multiple java dependency projects(TestCommon,TestModule).

I was able to build all 3 projects using maven.It has created war file and jar file out of it.

I need to create .ear file using maven. How can I create ear and build them?

TestWeb/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TestWeb</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestWeb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>TestCommon</groupId>
            <artifactId>TestCommon</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>TestModule</groupId>
            <artifactId>TestModule</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: take a look at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<packaging>ear</packaging>` instead of `<packaging>war</packaging>`.